# IOS/Objective-C: Access to variables within switch statements

Tags: ios, objective-c, switch-statement

I have a switch statement that in most cases returns static values but in a few cases, I would like to call a function to get a value. Accordingly, I have put curly braces inside the case which apparently defines a scope for variables.

I can get the value within the scope of the switch case but am having trouble getting it out of the case so that I can use it later.

When I do:

```
case 2018:
         {
             NSString * myText = [self getMyText];
             NSArray *myTextArr = [myText componentsSeparatedByString:@"**"];
             responseOptions = myTextArr;
         }
myOutsideArr = myTextArr;  ///This throws an undeclared identifier error
             break;
```

`responseOptions` is not recognized outside the braces.

Is there any way to access the value from the scope defined by the braces?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Then define it before the brace even the switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ways to have access to data inside ***case*** from outside.

But in reason that ***switch-case*** with *break* implies that you have only one coincidence for case values you can save case data in outside variable without fear of being overwriting.
So you can do it like this:

```
NSArray *myOutsideArr = [NSArray array];
int year = 2018;
switch (year) {
    case 2018: {
        NSString * myText = [self getMyText];
        NSArray *myTextArr = [myText componentsSeparatedByString:@"**"];
        myOutsideArr = myTextArr;
        break;
    }
    case 2017: {
        // ...
    }
}
```